# Unit testing properties for Page Models in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, razor-pages

I have a simple Page Model, `PizzaModel`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace starting_app.Pages
{
    public class PizzaModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Customer {get; set;}
        public int Total {get; set;}
        public string SomeProperty {get; set;}   

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the `NUnit` framework to test for certain properties:

```cs
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using blank_workspace.Pages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;


namespace starting_app.UnitTests
{
  [TestFixture]
  public class Tests
  {
      [Test]
    public void PizzaModel_Asserts_Customer_Property()
    {
      PizzaModel pm = new PizzaModel();


      Assert.That(pm, Has.Property("Customer"));
    }
  }
}
```

Is this the right format?

I'm currently getting another type of error:

> The type or namespace name ‘NUnit’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But I'm trying to get my syntax correct.

Comment: You appear not to have referenced the framework assembly from your test assembly.